# Hybris: How to trigget hourly a cronjob?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I want to trigger myCronJob hourly. Is my expression correct?

```
INSERT_UPDATE Trigger;cronjob(code)[unique=true];cronExpression
#% afterEach: impex.getLastImportedItem().setActivationTime(new Date());
;myCronJob; 0 0 * * * ?
```

Thanks!

Comment: Similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48902966/hybris-how-to-schedule-cornjob-to-work-from-7am-to-11pm

Answer (score 2):

The Cron expression is not correct, you must use `* * * * * ? *` as a cron expression to trigger your job every hour.

You can try this too :

```
INSERT_UPDATE Trigger   ;cronJob(code)[unique=true] ;active ;year   ;month  ;day    ;hour   ;minute ;second ;relative   ;weekInterval   ;daysOfWeek
                                ;myCronJob  ;true       ;-1 ;-1     ;0      ;1      ;0          ;0          ;true           ;0                  ;
```